# Using Wicket to display an image stored as BLOB in MYSQL db

Tags: mysql, image, hibernate, wicket, blob

I currently have a blob in my mysql db that contains an image.
What i want is to display this image to the user.

I cannot place it in a directory structure as the blob may be anything from an image to a piece of html so there is logic involved as to whether it is a piece of html or an image etc.

I was thinking of checking the BLOB to see if it is an image and it can output it to a temporary directory then load it as a resource but then I noticed wicket has a BlobImageResource class however I am not sure how this is to be implemented and am unable to find any examples after searching on google.

Any suggestions how best to go about doing this ?

i am using wicket 6.xx and have access to spring and hibernate and am not against using third party libraries

Comment: do you control the upload process? you could save the content-type to the db, along with the blob.

Comment: in the worst case, you could use *nix's [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) command and parse the result with tons of ifs. :)

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687688/wicket-dynamic-resource-displayed-in-html . Just check the magic bytes of the blob to determine if it is an image. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: you should always store the data type (mime type) with your blob to ensure proper loading of the data.

Comment: what is your problem exactly? showing a dynamic image or detecting blob content type?

Comment: Yes thankyou everyone for the comments; i am of course aware that I should be storing the content type in the db to avoid this problem but i do not control the upload process so cannot do this meaning i needed a way to read the blob's mime type on the fly

Answer (score 1):

```
private byte[] blob = some data...;
```

to check blob is an image:

```
Boolean isImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(blob)) != null;
if( isImage ){
    // blob is an image...
}
```

create a IResource object and show in html:

```
IResource imageResource = new DynamicImageResource() {
                @Override
                protected byte[] getImageData(IResource.Attributes attributes) {
                    return blob;
                }
            };
Image image = new Image("wicketId", imageResource);
this.add(image);
```

in html file use:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <img wicket:id="wicketId"/>
</wicket:panel>
```

Comment: This is working fine with the PNG images. To use with another image format, we have to set the format like this: imageResource.setFormat("svg+xml"); // For image/svg+xml

Answer (score 0):

**Wicket code for blob image from MySql DB to HTML page**

public class BlobToImage extends WebPage{

```
private static Blob blob;
public BlobToImage() {

    BlobImageResource blobImgSrc = new BlobImageResource() {

        @Override
        protected Blob getBlob(Attributes attributes) {             
            return blob;
        }
    };
    try {
        getBlob();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    Image img = new Image("image", blobImgSrc);
    add(img);
}

public static void getBlob() throws SQLException{
    Properties ConProps = new Properties();
    ConProps.put("user","root");
    ConProps.put("password", "root");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/google_map",ConProps);
    System.out.println(conn);

    java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute("SELECT id,image FROM images where id=1");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    while(rs.next()){
        try{
            blob = rs.getBlob("image");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}
**The following HTML code helps to show the image at the webpage**

```
    Image <img wicket:id="image"  alt="image">
```