# Displaying blob file in wicket

Tags: mysql, database, iframe, wicket, blob

I am trying to display a file stored in mysql database in iframe, but it is not working. Can anyone suggest a better way. My files will be pdf,word or any other format.

I am using wicket, spring and hibernate frameworks.

Comment: can you show some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Use the search.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636563/using-wicket-to-display-an-image-stored-as-blob-in-mysql-db#comment30900465_20636563

Comment: Are you getting some error. Images are easy to display because wicket has out of the box support for image component, for other file types like pdf, word you would have to read those documents and parse them if you want to show them as a part of a web page